# Compiling Hadoop wordcount tutorial - hadoop 2.6.3

Tags: java, hadoop

The following is my system configuration: windows8.1, vmware v12, 2 centOS VMs. I have installed hadoop on my VMs, one as master and the other as slave1. The services are correctly up and running on both nodes.

I want to compile my first mapreduce program, the wordcount tutorial:
I'm trying to compile using the following:

```
[hadoop@master ~]$ javac -classpath $HADOOP_HOME/share/common/hadoop-common-2.6.3.jar:$HADOOP-HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.6.3.jar:$HADOOP_HOME/share/common/lib/common-cli-1.2.jar -d /home/hadoop *.java
```

but the answer I get is this:

```
WordCount.java:4: error: package org.apache.hadoop.conf does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
                             ^
WordCount.java:5: error: package org.apache.hadoop.fs does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
                           ^
WordCount.java:6: error: package org.apache.hadoop.io does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
                           ^
WordCount.java:7: error: package org.apache.hadoop.io does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
                           ^
WordCount.java:8: error: package org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce does not exist
(.
.
.)                                       ^
  symbol:   class Path
  location: class WordCount
WordCount.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    ^
  symbol:   variable FileOutputFormat
  location: class WordCount
40 errors
```

I googled and everyone said it's due to $CLASSPATH.

this is my /etc/bashrc file:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk
export JRE_HOME=/opt/jdk/jre
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/jdk/bin:/opt/jdk/jre/bin
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop/
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$HADOOP_HOME/share/common/hadoop-common-2.6.3.jar:$HADOOP-HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.6.3.jar:$HADOOP_HOME/share/common/lib/common-cli-1.2.jar
```

any idea why I get this error?? I see no problem... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation you can do the following (tested on my system and works)

- `export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar`
- `$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main WordCount.java` 
  and finally create the jar using
- `jar cf wc.jar WordCount*.class`

[link to the official doc here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Source_Code)